# Is this right way to update the value on main thread for UI change?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

In iOS, I am trying google charts to update in uiwebview. I am using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global...) for parsing json information. Inside async call, I am using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue...) for executing UI elements on the main thread. I am still finding some delay on the screen but there is no UI hang. Please help me how to write the below code in a better way so that as soon as I get value from parsed info, I should be able to generate the chart with no delay. Below is the code:

```
dispatch_queue_t syncInAsync=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);   
dispatch_async(syncInAsync, ^{        
[self parse:url];    
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{           
 NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);function drawChart() {var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Reports', 'Value'],['Total',     %@ ]]);var options = {title: 'Total Reports'};var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));chart.draw(data, options);}</script></head><body><div id=\"piechart\" style=\" text-align: left width: 400px; height: 200px;\"></div></body></html>",number];           
            [_web1 loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please show your `parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

Update UI using `sync` instead of async thread .
Try this -

```
 dispatch_queue_t syncInAsync=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0); dispatch_async(syncInAsync, ^{ [self parse:url]; dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);function drawChart() {var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Reports', 'Value'],['Total', %@ ]]);var options = {title: 'Total Reports'};var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));chart.draw(data, options);}</script></head><body><div id=\"piechart\" style=\" text-align: left width: 400px; height: 200px;\"></div></body></html>",number]; [_web1 loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil]; }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

write what you want to change in this block

```
   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
//type here
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly doing it the right way. I would want to make couple of changes:

I would like to let parse method execute code to render on UI. So, pass a completion block like this. Showing a loading overlay while parsing is going on is always a good idea:

```
- (void)parse:(NSString *)iURL withCompletionBlock:MyCompletionBlock)iCompletionBlock {
   // Parse JSON here. Show Loading Overlay.

   // Once response is available
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Remove Loading Overlay.

        // Execute completion block
        completionBlock();
    });
}
```

This is how your caller would look like:

```
dispatch_queue_t syncInAsync=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(syncInAsync, ^{
    [self parse:url withCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);function drawChart() {var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Reports', 'Value'],['Total',     %@ ]]);var options = {title: 'Total Reports'};var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));chart.draw(data, options);}</script></head><body><div id=\"piechart\" style=\" text-align: left width: 400px; height: 200px;\"></div></body></html>",number];
    [_web1 loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}];
```